# Can I install chromedriver on python anywhere and not use it headless?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, pythonanywhere

I am trying to use this code that works on my local machine on python anywhere and i want to understand if it is even possible:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Initialize webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/matteo/Downloads/chromedriver")

# Navigate to website
driver.get("https://apnews.com/article/prince-harry-book-meghan-royals-4141be64bcd1521d1d5cf0f9b65e20b5")

time.sleep(5)
# Parse page source
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

# Find desired elements using Beautiful Soup
elements = soup.find_all("p")

# Print element text
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)

# Close webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Do i need to have installed chrome to make that work or is chromium enough? Because when i run that code on my local machine a chrome page opens up. How does that work on python anywhere? Would it crush?

I am wondering if the code i am using only works if someone is on a GUI with Chrome installed or if it can work on python anywhere too.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. ChromeDriver must have chrome installed. You can run your tests headless for time save, but chrome still must be installed.